# Identifying availability of missing values in rows-R

Tags: r

I have such a data frame(df) with missing values:

df:

```
head1   head2   head3
-----   -----   -----
34      32      6
NA      NA      45
45      NA      11
54      15      98
45      56      NA
3       1       78
NA      5       NA
```

I want to return such a column(head4)

```
head1   head2   head3  head4
-----   -----   -----  -----
34      32      6      1
NA      NA      45     0
45      NA      11     0
54      15      98     1
45      56      NA     0
3       1       78     1
NA      5       NA     0
```

Namely, If one row has at least one missing value(NA), then related row will return 0 otherwise 1. How can I do that using R? I will be very glad for any help. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the logical matrix (`is.na(df1)`), get the `rowSums`, negate (`!`) so that 0 NA values in a row becomes TRUE and all others FALSE.  Then, wrap it with `as.integer` to convert the TRUE to 1 and FALSE to 0.

```
df1$head4 <- as.integer(!rowSums(is.na(df1)))
```